# Meaning of Cognos property Use for Parameter Info

Tags: performance, cognos

I am trying to understand the property 'Use for Parameter Info' in cognos report studio. At this link: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21341901 
What is meant by `'set to Yes are checked for parameter information first'`

Does it mean it will check if the parameter value(s) is supplied? But that it will anyway check for all mandatory parameter(s). We have seen some performance improvement by setting this property to 'No'. Why setting it to 'No' improves performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter resolution can be very expensive on complex reports.  Cognos has to figure out on your reports/dashboards interface which prompts are required before certain queries can run etc... This gets more complex when you have parameter to parameter dependencies or filters.Especially when you have interactive reports where you have parameter controls on the same page as your report creating dashboard interactive effects.

You can think of Use Parameter For Info as a nice hint to help Cognos understand which queries are specifically used to provide parameter information to help with Report execution optimization.

Answer (score 0):

The property is on the query level. 
Usually it is good practice to have small queries that aimed for prompt values. 
When Cognos load the report it search where it can find the parameters values. 
If you set the small queries with Use Parameter Info to Yes, it will search these queries first, and this can enhance performance, especially on big reports with many queries inside. 
Some more information can be found here:

[What is Use for parameter info](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21341901) 
and here: 
[Cognos 8.3 Prompt Query Hint Settings](http://businessintelligence.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/cognos8-l/cognos-83-prompt-query-hint-settings-3336788)